# C# LINQ Group and sum List<T> then Group and sum another list within the first List

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to group results(data) of a list into another list to be displayed. What does the LINQ query need to be to get the results I'm looking for.

My first group by that I need is by the ProductId then within the result list I need to group again by the Sitename and I also want to sum totals within these groups.

--classes

```
public class Item
{
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public long TotalSold { get; set; }
    public long TotalOrders { get; set; }
    public long TotalAvailable { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastSold { get; set; }

    public List<MarketPlace> MarketPlaceList = new List<MarketPlace>();

}

public class MarketPlace
{
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public long SiteTotalQuantity { get; set; }
    public long SiteTotalOrders { get; set; }
}
```

--c# code

```
var rolledUpList =    from e in itemList
                      group e by e.ProductId
                      into newGroup
                      orderby newGroup.Key
                      select newGroup;

foreach (var nameGroup in rolledUpList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {nameGroup.Key}");
    foreach (var item in nameGroup)
    {

        Console.WriteLine($"\t{item.ProductId}, {item.PartNumber}, Total Orders({item.TotalOrders}) - Total Quantity ({item.TotalSold})");

        foreach (var m in item.MarketPlaceList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{m.SiteName}, Total Orders({m.SiteTotalOrders}) - Total Quantity ({m.SiteTotalQuantity})");
        }
    }
}
```

**---output produced**

```
Key: 42804

42804, L89509-WFL-EA, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)
 {Amazon Seller Central, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}
42804, L89509-WFL-EA, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)
 {Walmart Marketplace, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}
42804, L89509-WFL-EA, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)
 {Walmart Marketplace, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}

Key: 42812

42812, L89501-WFL-EA, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)
 {BigCommerce, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}
42812, L89501-WFL-EA, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)
 {Amazon Seller Central, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}
42812, L89501-WFL-EA, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)
 {Walmart Marketplace, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}
42812, L89501-WFL-EA, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)
 {Walmart Marketplace, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}
42812, L89501-WFL-EA, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)
 {Walmart Marketplace, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}

Key: 42943

42943, L80421-W-EA, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)
 {eBay, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}
42943, L80421-W-EA, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)
 {eBay, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}

Key: 43838

43838, L41080-6WP-EA, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)
 {Amazon Seller Central, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}
43838, L41080-6WP-EA, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (14)
 {BigCommerce, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (14)}
```

**--needed or expected**

```
Key: 42804

 42804, L89509-WFL-EA, Total Orders(3) - Total Quantity (3)
   {Amazon Seller Central, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}
   {Walmart Marketplace, Total Orders(2) - Total Quantity (2)}  

Key: 42812

 42812, L89501-WFL-EA, Total Orders(5) - Total Quantity (5)
   {BigCommerce, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}
   {Amazon Seller Central, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}
   {Walmart Marketplace, Total Orders(3) - Total Quantity (3)}

Key: 42943

 42943, L80421-W-EA, Total Orders(2) - Total Quantity (2)
   {eBay, Total Orders(2) - Total Quantity (2)}

Key: 43838

 43838, L41080-6WP-EA, Total Orders(2) - Total Quantity (15)
  {Amazon Seller Central, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (1)}
  {BigCommerce, Total Orders(1) - Total Quantity (14)}
```

Comment: Why does your "Output Produced" not match the code you show? Why does it show every `MarketPlaceList` only has one entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer needs a nested `group...by` - the outer grouping, then flattening the `MarketPlaceList`s and grouping them by `SiteName`:

```
var ans = from i in itemList
          group i by i.ProductId into ig
          let PartNumber = ig.First().PartNumber
          select new {
              ProductId = ig.Key,
              PartNumber,
              TotalOrders = ig.Sum(i => i.TotalOrders),
              TotalSold = ig.Sum(i => i.TotalSold),
              MarketPlaceList = (from m in ig.SelectMany(i => i.MarketPlaceList)
                                 group m by m.SiteName into mg
                                 select new {
                                     SiteName = mg.Key,
                                     SiteTotalOrders = mg.Sum(m => m.SiteTotalOrders),
                                     SiteTotalQuantity = mg.Sum(m => m.SiteTotalQuantity)
                                 }).ToList()
          };
```

I used anonymous types, but you could, of course, use your existing classes since the properties match.

Then your desired output is generated by:

```
foreach (var prod in ans) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {prod.ProductId}");
    Console.WriteLine($"\t{prod.ProductId}, {prod.PartNumber}, Total Orders({prod.TotalOrders}) - Total Quantity ({prod.TotalSold})");

    foreach (var m in prod.MarketPlaceList) {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{m.SiteName}, Total Orders({m.SiteTotalOrders}) - Total Quantity ({m.SiteTotalQuantity})");
    }
}
```